# How to select region/dynamic site location FaunaDB

Tags: faunadb

I was wondering how to select what cloud location your database resides in. Is it done programmatically or through the cloud interface?

Also, if you have data being transfered between your other cloud services in a region are you charged network egress rates? Example: between a FaundaDB in AWS and AWS lambda function in that same region.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got an answer on this from FaunaDB support.

> If you require the ability to select a specific provider and/or
>   location for your data and endpoint, you can deploy Fauna Enterprise
>   directly. Today, FaunaDB Cloud does not provide the ability to specify
>   a specific location for your data. Data stored will be replicated
>   across all the active data centers as seen here:
>   https://app.fauna.com/status.
>
> Our plan is to provide greater flexibility along these lines in the
>   future.